# Validando cadastro com filter validate regexp

Tags: php

Estou utilizando o filter validate regexp dessa forma:

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome', FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options" => array("regexp" => "/.[a-zA-ZÀ-ú\s]+$/"))
```

A validação funciona, o estranho é que se eu colocar apenas uma letra no campo do formulário, ele barra. Por exemplo:
Se eu colocar só "a" ele barra, mas se eu colocar "aa" ele funciona. Só a partir de duas letras ele valida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É por causa do `.` no começo, que é considerado a busca de "um caractere" e mais `[a-zA-ZÀ-ú\s]+`, que seria o segundo ou mais carácteres, veja a diferença:

- Com `.`: https://regex101.com/r/zVJ4FA/1
- Sem `.`: https://regex101.com/r/zVJ4FA/2

também não esqueça do `^` para que exija que a string comece e termine (com `$`) exatamente como a regex define, pois se não ele vai exigir apenas que termine, mas o começo poderá ter qualquer formato de entrada

Aproveite e também adicione o modificar `i`, para case-insensitive, assim não vai precisar de A-Z e a-z, fica assim: `/^[a-zà-ú\s]+$/i`

Então mude para:

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome', FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options" => array("regexp" => "/^[a-zà-ú\s]+$/i"))
```

> Note que para `unicode`, se estiver usando UTF-8 por exemplo, talvez tenha que usar o modificador `u`, assim: `/^[a-zà-ú\s]+$/iu`

Comment: Coloquei esse aqui: /^[a-zà-ú\s]+$/i e esse aqui: /^[a-zà-ú\s]+$/iu. Continua dando o mesmo problema.

Comment: Eu tinha testando antes sem o ponto também, mas tava dando esse problema.

Comment: Opa! Consegui aqui! Tinha esquecido de atualizar. rsrs